# Russian text not displaying in Jquery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using server side jquery DataTable to show the list of data. there is some **Russian (Cyrillic)** data in the list.We are getting data through database and put it into JSONObject and this object is taken by DataTable BUT I am getting ??? ???? in place of Russian Character.

**At Jsp page, I used**

added jsp tag at header `%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %`

**IN Controller, I used**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "view/{list}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8","/;charset=UTF-8"})



public void getList(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String showAll, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, JSONException { 

JSONObject result = new JSONObject(); PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
try {                                                                                //some code here
        result  = (JSONObject) abcDao.getList();
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out.print(result);
        model.put("result", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);                   
    }
}
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
 oTable = $('#test_table').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200, 500]],
            sPaginationType: "bootstrap",
            iDisplayLength: parseInt($("#recordsPerPage").val()),
            "sAjaxSource": "aa/view/getData.do",
            "aoColumns" : [
                                {"sTitle":"Status","sWidth" : "2%",sClass: "font-th","bSortable" : false,"aTargets": [ 0 ] },
                                {"sWidth" : "6%","bSortable" : true },
                                {"sWidth" : "5%","bSortable" : true },
                                {"sWidth" : "17%","bSortable" : true }
              ],
            "aaSorting": [[1, 'desc']],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": $('#datatTableRecordsPerPage').html()+"_MENU_",
                "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious":  $('#dataTablePaginationPrevious').html(),
                "sNext":  $('#dataTablePaginationNext').html()
                },
                "sSearch": $('#dataTableSearchField').html(),
                "sZeroRecords":$('#datatTableZeroRecords').html(),
                "sInfo": $('#datatTableInfoShowing').html()+" _START_ "+$('#datatTableInfoTo').html()+" _END_ "+$('#datatTableInfoOf').html()+" _MAX_ "+$('#datatTableInfoEntries').html(),
                "sProcessing":$('#Processing').html()
            },
            "sDom": '<"row-fluid"<"span4" <"span5" l>> <"span8"<"span8" <"paginationName"> p><"span2 searchStyle" f> >><"row-fluid"<"span3" ir>>t<"row-fluid"<"span4" i><"span4 lowerPaginationStyle" p>>',
            "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {


            },
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
                aoData.push({"name":"incidentId", "value":encodeURIComponent(id) },{"name":"msgType", "value":msg},{"name":"showAll", "value":'' }),
                oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                "dataType": 'json',
                "type": "POST",
                "url": sSource,
                "headers": {
                    'CRI_TOKEN': critoken
                },
                "contentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
                "data": aoData,
                "success": function(data){
                        fnCallback(data);
                }
                  } );
            }
        });
```

Please help me to find out where I am wrong.

Comment: and your database field is encoded in utf8 too?

Comment: yes database field is encoded .. when I get data from json object then I get ????? where as I get data from Spring model then it gives correct format ..It means database field is encoded

Thanks

Comment: And your HTML page is UTF8 encoded? EDIT: sorry, just seeing that now: `jsp tag at header %@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %`  Now i'm not jsp user so not sure what can go wrong, sorry